Is it possible to build Kafka streams application in Python?
Do Java and Scala only provide APIs for Kafka streams applications? Can I develop Kafka Streams application using Python code?
I already developed producer and consumer applications in Python but haven't found any resource for streaming (joins, windowing, aggregations).

I don't know Kafka but I use Google to search "kafka streams python" and first result was Stream Processing with Python and Apache Kafka: A Beginner’s Guide | by Daily Dose of Python | Medium. Is this what you need?

did you tried to use Python in similar way as in Scala? Maybe you have to only try to use some functions to see if it can work. And eventually you may need to search this function in documentation (and in eventually in source code)

I don't know Kafka but if you would show minimal working code in Scala then we may know what you need in Python. And we may try to search information about parts of code (which you show in Scala)

Thank You folks, for your answers. Kafka Streams is a Java library that we use to write our stream processing applications in Java. So Java has built in functions for doing Joining, aggregations, windowing.
Based on my investigation, in Python we need to create custom functions for that purpose.
